# RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 response on Google geocoding API request

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, restkit

I send a HTTP GET to the Google search API with RESTKit:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Sulgen
```

This URL works fine when beeing used with NSURLRequest.

RESTKit transforms this string to

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json/?sensor=false&address=Sulgen
```

Hint: a slash is inserted in the string before

I used the GET Method to fire the request. How is this supposed to work?

EDIT: here is the code that leads to the above behavior:

```
+ (void)loadGoogleMapsApiLocation_Restkit:(NSString*)searchString
{
/// String definitions
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Frankfurt"];

NSLog(@"requestString: %@",requestString);

/// Create Mappers
RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[GooglePlacemark class]];

[objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:
                       @[@"formatted_address"]];

/// setup responseDesriptor
NSString *key_path = @"results";

/// use this new Restkit method instead of the deprecated one
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:nil
                                            keyPath:key_path
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

/// Create Manager, connect responseDescriptor and execute
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

[manager getObject:nil
              path:@""
        parameters:nil
           success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
           {
               NSLog (@"sucess!");
           }

           failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
           {
               NSLog (@"Error: %@", error);
               NSLog (@"Response: %@", operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
           }
];
}
```

The error messages are these:

```
 I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:150 GET 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json/?sensor=false&address=Frankfurt'

E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:547 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 404" UserInfo=0xafaff00 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The 404 message comes because Restkit inserted the backslash into the request String.
The original string request works fine if fired in a browser or rest client.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It works by you showing the code you're using for your request, mapping, descriptors and then we suggest what you did wrong ;-)

Comment: You are right, I added the required code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reorganise your base URL and paths:

```
NSString *baseURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode"];

NSString *requestPath = @"json";

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"sensor":@"false",@"address":@"Frankfurt"};

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURLString]];

[manager getObject:nil
              path:requestPath
        parameters:parameters
                   ...
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks! I should have taken a closer look at the docs: http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectManager.html